# Locally hosted Polymer project URL path customization

Tags: polymer

```
 applications: http://localhost:8080
    reusable components: http://localhost:8080/components/myapp/
```

These are the two paths that allow me to access my prooject after I run `polymer serve`

Using `app-route` element, I can change the `myapp` part. But I want to remove the `components` part.
So, what I want is `http://localhost:8080/myapp/`
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are getting confused between urls represented by the server and the logical urls that "Normally" don't even get passed to the server.  `<app-route>` (and its companion part `<app-location>`) rely on pushing state into the address bar of the browser but that doesn't normally mean a request to the server to fetch a file.

I say "Normally" because obviously the user could copy and paste the address bar into the browser (or just refresh the page when its displayed in the browser) and that causes that url to be sent to the server.  Normally a server should automatically respond to those "Not real files" requests with "/index.html".

`Polymer serve` doesn't really try and address this sort of thing.  Its mainly a quick server for your application testing.  The first url it offers (http://localhost:8080) will be what you use if you have a full app.  Your index.html file should sit at the root of the url (ie the directory you run polymer serve from) and it will then use html imports to load your components from which ever subdirectories they happen to be in.  Your urls should reflect that. So if you main app is in the `src/` subdirectory you should refer to it `<link rel="import" href="/src/my-app.html">` NOTE IT IS IMPORTANT TO REFER TO IT VIA AN ABSOLUTE URL SO THAT WHEN A USER PASTES the url into the address bar and the server returns `/index.html` the elements it then requests are at the correct path and not somewhere like `/application/logical/path/src/myapp.html`

The second url it offers is basically you are building your own element that will ultimately go in someone elses bower_components but which for now your are developing in its own repository with its own bower_components directory at the same level as the element.  Your element will want to import something like `<link rel="import" href="../polymer/polymer.html" but in physical directory terms would be at bower_components/polymer/polymer.html.  In this case polymer is mapping  bower_components to http://localhost:8080/components and your root to http://localhost:8080/components/myapp.  So when your refer to`../`as part of your relative its basically inside`bower_components/` already and will therefore pickup the rest of the reference to your element OK.

Comment: Nice explanation. Thanks.